# JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance - Java

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm creating a REST service that receives a JSON input like this:

```
    [
      {
        "person": {
          "name": "string",
          "surname": "string",
          "address": "string",
          "age": "data",
          "info": {
            "number": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "person": {
          "name": "string",
          "surname": "string",
          "address": "string",
          "age": "data",
          "info": {
            "number": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

My items are(
I omitted getters and setters):

```
public class Request {
    private List<Person> person;        
}

public class Person{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address;
    private XMLGregorianCalendar age;
    private Info info;
}

public class Info {
    private String number;
}
```

how come i get the following error?

```
{
   "timestamp": 1611142052198,
   "status": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
   "message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of com.myproject.model.Request out of 
    START_ARRAY 
}
```

i need the json structure to be exactly that.

Comment: Your JSON represents an array, but it looks like you're trying to deserialize to a single object.

Comment: It tries to deserialize a complete `Request` object, but what you have should go to its `person` field only.

Comment: but my request is a list of Person, what should my classes be like?

Comment: @Vlenovil You should deserialize to `List<Person>` (or `Person[]`) instead of the `Request` class you use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to de-serialize your input array to a `Request` object, which is not a collection, and thus you get that error.

To solve it you should de-serialize your input array to a `List<Person>` object and then set that object to your `Request` object:

```
Request request = ... // get the request
List<Person> person = ... // deserialize the input array

request.setPerson(person);
```

If you are using Jackson, you can also define a constructor for your `Request` class which takes a `List<Person>` argument and then mark that constructor with the `@JsonCreator` annotation (see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#1-jsoncreator) for an example):

```
public class Request {
    private List<Person> person;

    @JsonCreator
    public Request(@JsonProperty("person") List<Person> person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

And then you can create your `Request` object directly from your input array.

By using the `@JsonCreator` annotation you keep your `Request` class immutable, because you don't need to define a `setPerson(List<Person>)` method for it.